# Open Visual Studio 2012 solution in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013

I have to open a Web Application created in Visual Studio 2012 in Visual Studio 2013.

The structure of the solution is with one project. The solution is called `OT` and the pages are in the folder `OTWEB/Web/OT`.

When I open the `.sln` with Notepad, it looks like this:

```
ProjectSection(WebsiteProperties) = preProject
        SccProjectName = "SAK"
        SccAuxPath = "SAK"
        SccLocalPath = "SAK"
        SccProvider = "SAK"
        Frontpage = "false"
        TargetFrameworkMoniker = ".NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.5"
        Debug.AspNetCompiler.VirtualPath = "/OT"
        Debug.AspNetCompiler.PhysicalPath = "..\OTWEB\Web\OT\"
        Debug.AspNetCompiler.TargetPath = "PrecompiledWeb\OT\"
        Debug.AspNetCompiler.Updateable = "true"
        Debug.AspNetCompiler.ForceOverwrite = "true"
        Debug.AspNetCompiler.FixedNames = "false"
        Debug.AspNetCompiler.Debug = "True"
        Release.AspNetCompiler.VirtualPath = "/OT"
        Release.AspNetCompiler.PhysicalPath = "..\OTWEB\Web\OT\"
        Release.AspNetCompiler.TargetPath = "PrecompiledWeb\OT\"
        Release.AspNetCompiler.Updateable = "true"
        Release.AspNetCompiler.ForceOverwrite = "true"
        Release.AspNetCompiler.FixedNames = "false"
        Release.AspNetCompiler.Debug = "False"
        VWDPort = "60588"
    EndProjectSection
```

The directory structure is like this - two main directories

```
OT--> Ot.Sln
OTWEB--> WEB --> OT --> Files, and Sources
```

When I run the application in Visual Studio 2012, locally points to

```
http://localhost:60588/OT/Login.aspx
```

But when I run it from Visual Studio 2013, it points to

```
http://localhost:60588/Login.aspx
```

It misses `OT` folder, and the pages are not found.

How can I do to search the pages in the `OT` folder?